# Server echoing back using Datagram Sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

I wrote this program called echo Server.It has two files i.e., a **sender**
and **receiver**.
The sender sends data using **Datagram sockets** and **Datagram packets** and the server(receiver) echoes the same thing back.
But the message echoed back is not the same as that is sent.
The output is not proper.Why is this happening?

**Sender Program**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class sender {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            int port = 1234;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String msg = br.readLine();
            byte[] buf = new byte[100];
            while(true){
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(),msg.length(),ip,port);
                if(!msg.equals("quit"))
                    ds.send(dp);
                else { ds.send(dp);break;}
                dp = new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);
                ds.receive(dp);
                msg = new String(buf);
                System.out.println(msg);
                msg = br.readLine();
            }           
            //ds.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Receiver(Server) Program**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class receiver {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(1234);                       
            DatagramSocket sds = new DatagramSocket();
            byte[] buf = new byte[100];
            String msg;
            DatagramPacket rdp,sdp;
            while(true)
            {                   
                rdp  = new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);          
                ds.receive(rdp);
                msg = new String(buf);
                msg = msg.trim();
                if(!msg.equals("quit"))
                    System.out.println(msg);
                else break;             
                sdp = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(),msg.length(),rdp.getAddress(),rdp.getPort());                       
                sds.send(sdp);
            }           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question has exactly nothing to do with [tag:rmi] or [tag:client-server]. Don't tag indiscrminately,

Comment: And don't post pictures of text here. Waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] buf = new byte[100];
```

Is created once, but afterwards never cleared. So when the next message is shorter than the previous a part of the old data remains and thus you get faulty data on both ends.

Try clearing the buffer at the start of your while loop.

```
while(true){
    buf = new byte[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
msg = new String(buf);
```

The problem is here. You're ignoring the length in the datagram. It should be:

```
msg = new String(rdp.getData(), rdp.getOffset(), rdp.getLength());
```

Then:

```
msg = msg.trim();
```

You don't need that. Remove.